# How to sink DataStream<MyProjectPOJO> to different Kafka topics using KafkaSink in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Using Apache Flink (1.17.2) I have created a `KafkaSource` which uses a regex topic pattern to collect data from many different Kafka topics. I want to sink the `DataStream<>` created after transforming this source's input to multiple different topics based on the data record.

I have created an input DataStream which will have data from multiple Kafka topics

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

KafkaSource<ESDInputPayload> esdKafkaSource = KafkaSource.<ESDInputPayload>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers("serverdetail")
        .setTopicPattern(Pattern.compile("^esd_.*"))
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(ESDInputPayload.class))

DataStream<ESDInputPayload> input = env.fromSource(esdKafkaSource,
        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "esd_input_payload");
```

I'm transforming the incoming records and I end up with a `DataStream<ESDOutputPayload> output` object. I now want to sink the records in `output` to different kafka topics based on what data they contain. For instance, this is what my ESDOutputPayload looks like:

```
public class ESDOutputPayload implements Serializable {
  private String esdID;
  private Date timestamp;
  private String payload;
  private String taskCategory;
  private String subtaskCategory;
  private String hostname;
  private String payloadId;

  // Constructor, Setters and Getters
}
```

I want to achieve the following result:

1. Sink each `ESDOutputPayload` record in `output` to a Kafka topic named: `String.format("out_esd_%s_%s_%s", esdID, taskCategory, hostname)`
2. ESDOutputPayload.payloadId to be used as partition key
3. Kafka topic which I want to sink to might not exist, it should get created if it don't exist already.

I'm new to Apache Flink and have no idea if what I want is even possible or not, need help from someone who's familiar with the topic

Comment: The answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804580/how-to-select-kafka-topic-dynamically-in-apache-flink-kafka-sink cover the flink-specific parts of this well.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Will KafkaSink create topics if they don't exist?

Comment: You can set auto.create.topics.enable to true in the KafkaSink config.